# Check if String has specific repetitive special characters only

Tags: java, regex

I have a string of format `^%^%^%^%`. I need to check if the string has nothing other than repetitive patterns of `^%`

For example

```
1. ^%^%^%^% > Valid

2. ^%^%aa^%^% > Invalid

3. ^%^%^%^%^%^% > Valid

4. ^%^%^^%^% > Invalid

5. %^%^%^%^% > Invalid
```

How do I do this in Java?

I tried :

```
String text = "^%^%^%^%^%";
if (Pattern.matches(("[\\^\\%]+"), text)==true) {
    System.out.println("Valid");
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}
```

However it gives me Valid for cases 4 and 5.

Comment: You can use this to check your regex here : https://regex101.com/ then you can use it in your program. Or you can check this site : https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html to learn how to construct a regex.

Comment: change your `[ ]` to `( )`. also you don't need either one of those: \\

Comment: Thanks, I think it works except that I still need \\

Comment: oh yeah the `^` does nees to be escaped. otherwise that would represent the beginning of input/line

Answer (score 3):

In your pattern you use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which matches only 1 of the listed characters and then repeats that 1+ times.

You could use that `^` to anchor the start of the string and end with `$` to assert the end of the string.

Then repeat 1+ times matching `\\^%`

```
^(?:\\^%)+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XWUSDl/1)

Comment: congrats. the only answer that explained what he did wrong

Comment: Thanks, the above works as well. How about using (\\^%)+ as the regex pattern?

Comment: @Nick That is also possible. You would get a capturing group which will contain the last iteration of `^%`

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern `^(?:\^%)+$`

Explanation:

`^` - match beginning of the string

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`\^%` - match `^%` literally

`(?:\^%)+` - match `^%` one or more times

`$` - match end of the string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/chT6Xi/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
if (str.replace("^%", "").isEmpty()) {
    …
}
```

The `replace` method replaces the string as often as possible, therefore it fits exactly what you need.

It also matches the empty string, which, according to the specification, "contains nothing else than this pattern". In cases like these, you should always ask whether the empty string is meant as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] text = {"^%^%^%^%","^%^%aa^%^%","^%^%^%^%^%^%","^%^%^^%^%","%^%^%^%^%" };
for (String t: text) {
    if(Pattern.matches(("[\\^\\%]+[a-z]*[a-z]*[(\\^\\%)]+"), t)==true) {
            System.out.println("Valid");
    } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
    }
```

}

Comment: The regular expression must not contain any letter. That's either wrong or superfluous.